# How are cardiac cells connected by intercalated discs?

Tags: neurophysiology, cardiology

I understand that intercalated discs run transversely across the longitudinal axis of the muscle. But what I don't understand is how this same disc binds the cardiac cells together.
Are the cells joined end-to-end (in series) or side-to-side (in parallel) by the disc?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://www.britannica.com/science/cardiac-muscle?

Comment: This helps a lot.